# Visual Studio 2015 reinstall: ugly CSS editor, no color picker. Why?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, less

I was forced to reinstall VS 2015 update 3.
Before reisntall I have this CSS/LESS editor, as I like and working with. this one have  color picker & more:
[image: before upgrade]

After the upgrade, I see this one, with  far-away autocomplete and  no color picker:

[image: after upgrade]

Why I am seeing this? how to fix it?

`Open With` did not show a CSS editor in the list.

Comment: Try installing Web Essentials.

Comment: Tried, and I see this error: following references are missing: - Web Developer Tools.  I am working on it. strange.

Comment: Resintall Visual Studio; something is messed up.

Comment: Tried 3 times again and again. still not working.

Comment: Try deleting ComponentModelCache https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/371#issuecomment-135567147

Comment: @SLaks, your commend was the first path to the  answer. the Web Essentials was failed to install with the correct error message, and than I could go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: found the problem. I was  uninstalled  `AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe` (ASP.NET 5 RC1).

After this successful uninstall, I could open  VS install, and see the `Web Tools` was unchecked. After the Unchecked, I can Reinstall them again without restart.

ref:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6724bba-8d10-46f4-bb50-3d703f258a79/vs-2015-microsoft-web-developer-tools-missing?forum=visualstudiogeneral